# Timespan between Now and Next Hour?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

It is 8:30 and I am trying to find out how many seconds there are between now and the next whole hour (9:00). I think I just want to `DateTime.Now.AddHours(1`) but after I do that I think I need the "floor". How to get that value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just round the time of day in hours up to the next integral value:

```
var timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var nextFullHour = TimeSpan.FromHours(Math.Ceiling(timeOfDay.TotalHours));
var delta = (nextFullHour - timeOfDay).TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 8):

//Completely misread.  Completely re-writing

I woudl just do something Like this

```
int minutesToNextHour = 60 - DateTime.Now.Minutes;
int secondsToNextHour = minutesToNextHour * 60;
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to mess around with ceilings and floors. The [**`DateTime.Hour`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx) property represents *whole* hours (it is an integer beteen 0 and 23) of the time of the day represented by the DateTime. You can use this and the [**`DateTime.Date`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property to strip the components of the DateTime you don't want (sub-hour data) and then just subtract as necessary to produce a `TimeSpan`.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var timeToNextHour = now.Date.AddHours(now.Hour + 1) - now;
```

You can of course extract the `TotalSeconds` component of the resulting `TimeSpan` if you want the result in seconds.

Comment: This always equals 1 hour.  You need to remove the minutes somehow.

Comment: @smoore: No, it doesn't. It's correct. `DateTime.Hour` is an `int` that represents *whole* hours.

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be the most simple:

```
3600 - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds % 3600
```

(if you want it in whole numbers - integer - then prefix `DateTime.Now...` with `(int)`.

Comment: it's actually: 3600 - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds % 3600.

But +1 for the shortest solution.

Comment: @NightDweller I guess you commented an earlier version of the answer. It´s corrected :)

Comment: :) so many different solutions so fast - you're bound to miss something. this may not be a competition (and it IS) - but i think you should win :)

Comment: oh - and i think you mean _most_ simple :)

Comment: @NightDweller Thanks :) English is, unfortunately, not my native tongue.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if you explained why the number is `3600`.

Answer (score 1):

So you'd need to subtract the 'remainder' minutes, find the difference, and multiply that by 60, right?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
int secondsTillNextHour = (60 - now.Minute)*60+(60-now.Second);
```

Or (maybe clearer):

```
int SecondsTillNextHour = 3600 - 60*now.Minute - now.Second;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
 var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
 var hour = currentTime.AddHours(1).Hour;
 var newTime = Convert.ToDateTime(hour + ":00");
 var timespan = newTime.Subtract(currentTime);
 var secondsDiff = timespan.TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan sec = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3600 - (DateTime.Now.Minute * 60));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimeSpan result =  (new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 
DateTime.Now.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour + 1, 0, 0)).Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

Basically here you are building a new DateTime that is one hour on from Now, with no minutes or seconds, then you subtract Now from this and have your result.

Answer (score 1):

A more readable version:

```
public double SecondsToNextHour()
{
  return SecondsToNextHour( DateTime.Now );
}

public double SecondsToNextHour( DateTime moment )
{
  DateTime currentHour = new DateTime( moment.Year, moment.Month, moment.Day, moment.Hour, 0, 0 );
  DateTime nextHour = currentHour.AddHours( 1 );
  TimeSpan duration = nextHour - moment;
  return duration.TotalSeconds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would Timespan.Parse 08:30, add 1 hr to the object, then retrieve the hour part and build a new string with :00 as the minutes and reparse the new string. There may be a more efficient way to do this, but I find this technique clear to read.