# Start Task at specific time

Tags: c#, .net

I have an class which derives from `IHostedService`. In here I have the override method `StartAsync` as shown below:

```cs
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _timer = new Timer(DoSomething, null, offset, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In here I have the variable offset which is of the TimeSpan class.

**What I need:**

I need to calculate the offset in such way that the task "DoSomething" will be executed every start of an hour, like: 10:00, 13:00, 21:00 or 00:00. So this offset needs to be in minutes.

**Example** :
Let's say the application starts running at `13:48PM`, the correct offset would be 12 minutes and the next hour would be `14`.

**My question:**
How would I calculate the offset which is in minutes until next hour ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show any research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timespan between Now and Next Hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733521/timespan-between-now-and-next-hour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like

```
var minutes = (DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour+1)-DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be:

```cs
TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60 - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Minute);
```

But is there any other (better)way to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), there is official version of `TimedHostedService` class

You can use cron parsing nuget pacakge ([NCronTab.signed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncrontab.signed/)) to calculate the time based on configuration, and it will become a nice looking solution

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;
    private readonly CrontabSchedule _cronSchedule;

    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _cronSchedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse("0 * * * *");
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var nextOccurance = _cronSchedule.GetNextOccurrence(now);
        _logger.LogInformation("Configuring next run at: {time}", nextOccurance);
            
        await Task.Delay(nextOccurance - now, stoppingToken);

        DoWork()

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        
        _logger.LogInformation(
            "Timed Hosted Service is working. Count: {Count}", count);
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service is stopping.");

        _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }
}
```